# Ho do I filter a dataset from another dataset

Tags: r

I have this filtering to remove those who had order before activation

```
 filtered<-filter(mydata, Order_Date <= ActivationDate)
```

Which is fine but also I need all data in `mydata` which are not in `filtered`. I can not simply write `filtered<-filter(mydata, Order_Date > ActivationDate)` because it is a bit complicated  and some of the data will be ignored (unless I use heaps of conditions). is there anyway to have something like that?

```
 mydata [!filtered]
```

Comment: Um.... yep. By using selections just like you have. `filtcases <- mydata$Order_Date <= mydata$ActivationDate` just returns a bunch of `c(TRUE, FALSE,...)` etc. Save that to a variable and then you can negate it just like you have. `!filtcases`

Comment: @thelatemail. That's awesome! thank you so much